# Is a pivot table the best solution?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a very basic question regarding pivot tables and best practice for a specific piece of functionality.

In essence, I have two entities

Players
Questions

I display a question to a player, and when they answer, I fire an event to reward them points or not depending on if they answered correctly or not. What I want to do now is create a table to store what question the player has answered. So in the event, I can associate the player with a question.

something like,

```
$player->question()->associate($question);
```

This will be on a many to many relationship between the player and the question.

my question here however is this:

Is this the best solution in terms of practicality and scalability, as well as, how would I go about getting the questions that the player hasn't answered in the controller.

basically the opposite of

```
$player->questions();
```

If I was to use a many to many relationship

UPDATE

Models
PlayerProfiles

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\Pointable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\Transformable;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\TransformableTrait;

/**
 * Class PlayerProfiles
 * @package App\Models
 */
class PlayerProfiles extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait, Pointable;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $modelName = 'PlayerProfiles';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['msisdn'];

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModelName()
    {
        return $this->modelName;
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Questions')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Questions

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\Transformable;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\TransformableTrait;

class Questions extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait, SoftDeletes;

    protected $modelName = 'Questions';

    protected $fillable = ['question', 'correct_answer', 'incorrect_answer', 'category_id', 'language_id', 'difficulty_level_id'];

    public function getModelName()
    {
        return $this->modelName;
    }

    public function playerProfiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PlayerProfiles')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePlayerQuestionsPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('player_questions', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->tinyInteger('player_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('question_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('player_questions');
    }
}


<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddForeignKeysToPlayerQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('player_questions', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('player_profiles')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('player_questions', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('player_questions_questions_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('player_questions_player_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, that is a typo on my part, updating now

Comment: Then yes, that is the best solution. Then you can add the answer in there as well. Then you have a log of what the players actually answered.

Comment: Cool, this seems right in my head, in terms of getting a question a player hasn't answered yet, would you think that creating a trait that runs this query would suffice?

Comment: I don't know anything about your code or the architecture, so it's impossible for me to comment about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually only 2 questions here to answer: Can a player answer to multiple questions? And: Can one question be answered by many players? If the answer is YES, then automatically you need a pivot table. That is the best practice.

Comment: Player will answer multiple questions and and questions can be answered by multiple players

Comment: That's it then! As I have said...you need a pivot table for that.